# How to say that you are available

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

Recently I received an email in which I am asked whether I have time for a short call. I want to say that I am available every day, but I am not available from 3 till 5 PM.

Can I say "I am available every day except from 3 till 5 PM" or "I can be reached at everyday except from 3 till 5 PM"?

Are there any better ways to say it?

Comment: I’m free every day except between 3 and 5pm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I say "I am available every day except from 3 till 5 PM" or "I can
>   be reached at everyday except from 3 till 5 PM"?

A possible solution could be

> "I am available 24/7 (except 3 to 5 PM)"

You can add unavailability for evening hours if you so desire:

> "I am available every day from 8 am to 10 pm (with the exception of 3 pm to 5 pm)"

Comment: *Everyday* should be two words there.

Answer (score 2):

Setting everything else aside, I think that "from 3 till 5" should be "**from 3 to 5**" or "**between 3 and 5**" (my preference).  And "every day" does not say anything at all about the hours when you are available, it only says the days on which you are available.
Best would be

> *Every day, any time except between 3 and 5*.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use availability in your post?

My availability is really flexible and almost anytime with the only know exception being from 3:00 pm thru 5:00 pm daily. Other than that I will be on standby at the time of call.